# How to set the deleter for an existing shared pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, shared-ptr

I need to write my own destructor for a shared pointer instance. Unfortunately, such instance is acquired from a library function call and it's not I that initialize it. So how can I "set" the destructor here?

Ideally, the code in my mind may look like

```
pointer.setDeleter(myDeleter);
```

or

```
pointer = std::make_shared<MyType>(pointerOld.get(), myDeleter);
```

I didn't find the API for the first assumption. For the second one, it is said that `MyType` doesn't have a constructor with 2 parameters. It is not compilable.

Any ideas for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want this? Presumably the library doesn't want you screwing with their deleter.

Comment: @GManNickG   Because I'm using the library with event base mechanism. Therefore I want the deleter to be called in a certain thread (ie. the thread of the event base). Otherwise, the deleter will introduce segment fault.

Comment: Do you need the deleter to be called when they release the last reference to their shared pointer, or is it enough that you create a new shared pointer (with its own lifetime) that extends the life of the source shared pointer and, when it goes to zero, runs extra code?

Comment: @Yakk  Ideally I want the deleter to be called for the original instance when its counter goes to 0. Because creating a new pointer as the second way may cause a dangling pointer. I list it here only for a possible makeshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest I can get.

```
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<T> extra_deleter( std::shared_ptr<T> in, std::function<void(T*)> action ) {
  if (!in) return {};
  if (!action) return std::move(in);
  // action=std::move(action) in c++14
  auto new_deleter = [action](std::shared_ptr<T>* tin) { 
      action(tin->get());
      delete tin;
    };

  auto tmp = std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>>(
    new shared_ptr<T>(std::move(in)),
    std::move(new_deleter)
  );
  if (!tmp) return {};
  // aliasing ctor:
  return {tmp, tmp.get()->get()};
}
```

this create a shared pointer shared pointer, augments it with a custom deleter action, then uses the aliasing ctor to create a shared pointer to T.

This does not cause extra code to run when the *source* `shared_ptr` is destroyed.  Instead it creates a new `shared_ptr` with extra destruction code in it.  When the new lineage of `shared_ptr` dies, the `action` is run.

If there are no other references to the original `shared_ptr` state remaining, then the original destroyer of the `shared_ptr` runs.

Comment: Sorry I didn't fully get your idea  - I'm relatively new to C++11. Can you show me how to call this function (especially when the deleter is a non-static member function of a class (actually all these stuffs are in one class))? Also, I didn't understand the last return statement: why do we have these two parameters in the **curly** bracket?

Comment: @zzy pass in a lambda that takes a `T*` as the `action`, like `[](T* foo){std::cout<<(void*)foo<<'\n';}` to print the pointer value.  Pass in a `shared_ptr<T>` as the first argument.  It returns an augmented shared ptr that, when its reference count expires, it invokes the action.  Then it abandons a reference count on the source shared_ptr.  It still points at the same `T`.  `return {a,b};` is a way to directly call a ctor of the return value with `a,b`.  The original shared ptr state is not modified.